# Introducing ENTITY into oXygen causes Xerces "Element type ... must be declared" error

Tags: xml, dtd, xerces, xml-entities, oxygenxml

I have the following, very simple XML file (significantly cut back from the original for the purposes of this question):

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE root [
    <!ENTITY % entities SYSTEM "test.dtd">
    %entities;
    ]>

    <root>
    </root>
```

The file `test.dtd` exists but, again for the purposes of this question, is empty.

The trouble is that oXygen XML Editor throws the error:

```
E [Xerces] Element type "root" must be declared.
```

If I remove the `%entities;` line or the `%` symbol from the line above, no error is thrown because oXygen then is not actually parsing the entities file (so, obviously, when genuine entities are introduced the references to them fail). Unfortunately, the research I have done suggests that Xerces throws this error for a multitude of different reasons and I cannot narrow down what is wrong in this case.

Why is this error thrown when Entities are introduced, even when there are none there, and what can I do about it?

oXygen v10.3, if that matters (my company is only licensed for five-year old software :-( )

Comment: How do you not get a "There is no schema or DTD associated with the document." error when you try to validate? I don't get any well-formedness errors with the sample above, but it definitely won't validate because there is no DTD/Schema to validate against. If I add `<!ELEMENT root (#PCDATA)>` to the internal subset, it validates fine (with the empty `test.dtd`). (This is in oXygen 15.)

Comment: Not sure why I don't get that error. I'm not really trying to validate (except for continuous automatic validation that oXygen does) but my XML knowledge is not great and I don't understand why adding empty Entities causes it to throw an error. 
I suspect that the problem is with some settings in oXygen - Microsoft XML Notepad 2007 (what is it with me and old software?! ;-) ) deals with it fine.

Answer (score 0):

> The file `test.dtd` exists but, again for the purposes of this question, is empty.

Your simply get this error, because even if the file *test.dtd* is properly found, it does not contain anything, and in particular there is no declaration for the "root" element. Thus Xerces throws you the error:

> `E [Xerces] Element type "root" must be declared.`

If you simply declare  `<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "test.dtd">` (which is stricly equivalent to what you have done above), I bet you will obtain the same error.